# compare list of words, similar words deleted and added into new string

Tags: python, string, list, python-3.6

I have 2 strings which I have converted into a list of words A and B. I am trying to make an algorithm that selects a word starting from the left. If that word appears as a word or part of a word in the second string then add that word to a new common string and delete the entire first occurrence of the word where it was found in the second string. Upper and lowercase letters are considered different letters. I call this algorithm Diff.

Example:

```
List A: " The quick brown fox did jump over a log"
List B: " The brown rabbit quickly did outjump the fox"
```

If I were to Diff A to B, I would get " The quick brown fox did jump a"

If I were to Diff B to A, I would get " the brown did fox"

The code I have so far:

```
import re

a = 'The quick brown fox did jump over a log'
aa = re.sub("[^\w]", " ",  a).split()
b = 'The brown rabbit quickly did outjump the fox'
bb = re.sub("[^\w]", " ",  b).split()
print (aa)
print (bb)
```

The code above is what I used to change the string to a list of words.

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).  This usually suggests that what you need is time with a local tutor or walk through a tutorial, rather than Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could work

```
common_str = ""

a =  " The quick brown fox did jump over a log"
b = " The brown rabbit quickly did outjump the fox"
alist = a.split(" ")
blist = b.split(" ")
for item in blist:
    if item in alist:
        #add word to common string
        common_str += item + " "
        #remove from second string
        i = item + " " #item plus trailing space
        a.replace(i, "")
print(common_str)
print(a)
print(b)
```

Comment: This did work but, this diff'ed from B to A, Is there a way I can Diff from A to B? The outcome from A to B should be "The quick brown fox did jump a"

Comment: I just edited the code. It should do that now. If it works could you please upvote and accept my answer.

Comment: Previously the output was" The brown fox did" and now it is "the brown did fox". The only thing that changed was the last 2 words in the output

Answer (score -1):

```
a = 'The quick brown fox did jump over a log'
aa = a.split(" ")
b = 'The brown rabbit quickly did outjump the fox'
bb = b.split(" ")
common = []
for i in aa:
    for j in bb:
        if (i == j):
            common.append(j)
            break
print(" ".join(common))
```

The output for this will be "The brown fox did"

```
a = 'The quick brown fox did jump over a log'
aa = a.split(" ")
b = 'The brown rabbit quickly did outjump the fox'
bb = b.split(" ")
common = []
for i in bb:
    for j in aa:
        if (i == j):
            common.append(j)
            break
print(" ".join(common))
```

The output is "The brown did fox"

Comment: You have done the Diff from B to A, Is there a way to do it from List A to B?

Comment: just interchange the for loop , from aa to bb and bb to aa.

Comment: Will it look something like this: a = 'The quick brown fox did jump over a log'
aa = a.split(" ")
b = 'The brown rabbit quickly did outjump the fox'
bb = b.split(" ")
common = []
for i in bb:
    for j in aa:
        if (i == j):
            common.append(i)
            break
print(common)

Comment: yup, That will give you the diff A to B

Comment: It gives me the same output, even after interchanging

Comment: you should probably try different input string to differentiate better